# l() Link function adding Icon before Link Text

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

Is there a way to pass in an icon inside the  tag of the link built by using the link (*l()*) function?

```
<a href="#"><icon> Link Text</a>
```

I use it like so currently:

```
l('text','path',options)
```

Options all seem to be attributes of the  tag itself besides the "text". Using html =>true, I can add  before the link text:

```
print l('<span class="' . implode(" ",$link[options][attributes]["class"]) . '"></span> ' . $link["link_title"]
```

However, I cannot check if the span isset inline there, unless I am missing something...

This works (below), but all my `<a> have <a><span></span> linktext...` even if span is empty, and I don't want that blank tag in there:

```
<li class="nav-item"><?php print l('<span class="' . implode(" ",$link[options][attributes]["class"]) . '"></span> ' . $link["link_title"],$link["link_path"],array('attributes'=> array('class'=>array($link[options][item_attributes]["class"], 'nav-link')),'html' => TRUE)); ?></li>
```

How can I add an icon, without CSS, before my link text as well as check if that span is empty?

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
l(t('Back'), 'node/' . implode(" ",$link[options][attributes]["class"]) . '/edit/', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('btn btn-default btn-back'))))
```